# Z-index of an element won't show in Chrome

Tags: css, z-index

For days I've been trying to get an element with a z-index of 1 to show through the top parent element. When the page was first built, the element (a small bucket in the lowest right hand corner under the title "May/June") on page:
http://clifford-stage.scholastic.com/Calendar would did not need to be pushed into the corner but now since more text has been added it needed pushed over. I've moved the element around tremendously and placed it inside different containers, and turned positioning from absolute to relative, even of its parent(s), and have set negative z-index.

Here is the CSS of the element:

```
#bucket{
    top: 74px;
    right: -29px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

and it's parent's CSS (sorry, page is the page is too large to paste all of the code:

```
.yCenter{
     display:table-cell;
     vertical-align:middle;
     text-align:center;
     width:219px;
     height:112px;  
    }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
        <li class="oddBox">
            <div class="verticalAlign">
                <div class="yCenter">
                    <img alt="May and June Calendar" id="bucket" src="/resource/uploads_clifford/Calendar/img/may-june-img.png" />
                    <h4>
                        May/June</h4>
                    <p>
                        Ocean Habitat<br />
                        Summer Fun</p>
                    <h6>
                        Posters:</h6>
                    <p class="smallList">
                        &bull; Sea Animal &bull; Sink and     Float</p>
```

If there's more code that needs to be looked at, please let me know, but of course the page code can be viewed in Chrome inspect element tool.

Much appreciation to anyone who has a look.

Comment: I don't see any problem except it's clipped due to overflow:hidden in parent. ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from:

```
.verticalAlign {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: table;
width: 219px;
height: 112px;
}
```

Or set `overflow:visible` for that specific div in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't copy and paste the image somewhere, I just changed the top and left in the ID.

```
#bucket{
   left: -90px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -280px;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the **overflow:hidden** on the **.verticalAlign** rule

```
.verticalAlign {
   position: relative;
   /* overflow: hidden; */ /* remove this line */
   display: table;
   width: 219px;
   height: 112px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure Is this you're trying to show the bucket like this

[image]

```
#bucket {
top: 74px;
right: -7px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: No, trying to NOT show it like that. But j08691's solution worked...so obvious :-\ thanks a million!

Comment: @Jay, then you should accept j08691 his/hers answer. Have deleted my own answer.